# Can I migrate data into a relationship table in a Power Apps solution

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

I have an Oracle database that I'm migrating to Dataverse. The client has given me a managed Power Apps solution showing the new Dataverse tables and columns, that I can use to do the data mapping against.

In the Oracle db, I have a Brands table and an Organisations table. I have a mapping table between these two keeping track of the many-to-many relationship between Brands and Organisations. Pretty standard practice.

In the client supplied Power Apps solution, I can see the Brands and Organisations tables have been set up. I can see they have set up a many-to-many relationship in both of these tables, between the two tables Organisations <-> Brands.

I'm totally new to Power Apps and Dataverse. I have done a whole lot of reading and watching videos. I am under the impression that when the Organisations <-> Brands relationship was created, it would have automatically created a reference table between the two.

I am assuming this reference table would be where the Oracle mapping table data would need to be migrated into and stored. I have read that you can't view this reference table, and that seems to be true, since I can't see the reference table in the list of tables in the Power Apps solution. My question is, if I can't view this reference table, how do I know what columns it contains? If I don't know what columns it contains, how can I complete the data mapping exercise to document which columns from the Oracle mapping table need to be migrated into which columns from the relationship reference table. Another question I have is will it be possible to migrate this data into this reference table or does the reference table have any special properties that makes it impossible to migrate data into it?